# jQuery - Add input placeholder, ID number and row number dynamically

Tags: jquery

How can I increment 1 number for input placeholder, input ID and span text dynamically added row?

I am able to get the next number, but not getting incremental value.

> **[Online Demo](http://codepen.io/areddyprasad/pen/yYXpOq)**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-vote" id="addOption"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Option</a>

<div class="poll-options">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="po-number">1</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pollOption-1" placeholder="Option 1"></li>
    <li><span class="po-number">2</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pollOption-2" placeholder="Option 2"></li>
  </ul>             
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#addOption").click(function () {
  var optionCounter = 2;
  var qOption = '<li><span class="po-number">'+optionCounter+'</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pollOption-'+ optionCounter +' " placeholder="Option '+ optionCounter +' "><i class="fa fa-times remove-this"></i></li>';
  $(".poll-options ul").append(qOption);
  optionCounter++;
});

$(".poll-options").on("click", ".remove-this", function() {
  $(this).closest("li").remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `data-attribute`, and get the latest element attribute and increment it, this avoid duplicates and allow you to renumber them on the delete.

Code:

```
$("#addOption").click(function () {  
  var num = parseInt($('.po-number:last').attr('data-num'))+1;
  var qOption = '<li><span class="po-number" data-num="'+num+'">'+num+'</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pollOption-'+ num +' " placeholder="Option '+ num +' "><i class="fa fa-times remove-this"></i></li>';
  $(".poll-options ul").append(qOption);
});
```

Deletion and runumbering code:

```
$(".poll-options").on("click", ".remove-this", function() {  
  $(this).closest("li").nextUntil().each(function(i,e){
    var num = parseInt($(this).find("span").attr('data-num'))-1;
    $(this).find("span").attr("data-num", num).text(num);
    $(this).find("input").attr("id", "pollOption-"+num).attr("placeholder","Option "+num);
  });
  $(this).closest("li").remove(); 
});
```

The code use [`nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to take all the following siblings element and renumbering accordingly.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdqZBb

Comment: Thanks @Irvin Dominin, how can I reorder numbering on delete please?

Comment: **@Irvin Dominin**.. This is what exactly I want...

Thanks for saving my **DAY**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a dedicated counter here, just count the children of `ul` element:

```
$("#addOption").click(function () {
  var id = $(".poll-options ul").children().length + 1;

  if (id > 5) {
    return; // 5 is maximum
  }
  var qOption = '<li><span class="po-number">'+ id +'</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pollOption-'+ id +'" placeholder="Option '+ id +' "><i class="fa fa-times remove-this"></i></li>';
  $(".poll-options ul").append(qOption);
});
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWgxBg)

Comment: Thanks **@hsz**... Its working like a charm :). Once more thing please, how can I restrict maximum number of 'li' elements to 5?

Comment: @Reddy With simple `if` condition - look at my edit.

Comment: **@hsz** cool.. but while deleting, numbering is not working as expected.. for example, if I delete any li, number should automatically serialized.

I have updated my online demo **http://codepen.io/areddyprasad/pen/yYXpOq**

Comment: @Reddy You're right, sorry for my mistake. You should use Irvin Dominin answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `optionCounter` to a global variable as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    optionCounter = 3;
});

$("#addOption").click(function () {
    var qOption = '<li><span class="po-number">'+optionCounter+'</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pollOption-'+ optionCounter +' " placeholder="Option '+ optionCounter +' "><i class="fa fa-times remove-this"></i></li>';
    $(".poll-options ul").append(qOption);
    optionCounter++;
});

$(".poll-options").on("click", ".remove-this", function() {
    $(this).closest("li").remove(); 
});
```